# code igniter ajax error

Tags: php, codeigniter

my controller funnction

```
    public function give_form()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('use'))
    echo "user";
    else
    echo "sassa";
}
```

i am calling this function with ajax
my ajax code is this

```
function discount(){
alert('hi');
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();  ?>" + "index.php/home/give_form",
    type: "post",
    data: "cityy="+city,
    success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
    }
});
```

}

i am not getting any result from controller funciton!!!

Comment: What error do you get? what is the js data variable cityy for? Is your url correct? try putting in this 'statusCode : { 404: function(){alert('Not Found');} },' within the AJAX block.

Answer (score 2):

> try this
>   this is working for me

```
function discount(){
alert('hi');
 $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();  ?>/index.php/home/give_form",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: {cityy: city},
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response)
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change in your ajax Url

```
url: "<?php echo base_url();  ?>" + "index.php/home/give_form"
```

To

```
 url: <?php echo base_url();  ?> + "index.php/home/give_form"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function discount(){
alert('hi');
var base_url = window.location.origin;
jQuery.ajax({
   url: base_url + "/index.php/home/give_form",
   type: "post",
   data: "cityy="+city,
   success: function(response) {
   alert(response);
 }
});
```